# Bulk delete of images & folders in P&T Assets

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, delete

I want to clear out all of the files and folders in Assets.  We have been testing and am now ready to start using in anger.  Is there a way to do this without deleting directly in the DB?

Many thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can multi-select files in the Assets module control panel, then right-click and choose "Delete" from the custom contextual menu.